# kotlin coroutines - withContext vs suspendCoroutine

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

i was wondering since both [withContext](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) and [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) are suspend functions is there any difference betweeen them other then the fact that suspendCoroutine offers a continuation so you can control when it resumes or cancels if we use suspendCancellableCoroutine variation.
I would say both can be used to stop making callbacks (which is one advantage of coroutines). is there any major difference ?

Comment: `suspendCoroutine` is used within the `withContext`. The withContext adds another functionality to change the Context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually only `suspendCoroutine` can be used to translate a callback-based API into coroutines. `withContext` doesn't have the effect of suspending a coroutine, but temporarily changing its context (this is mainly about changing the dispatcher). The coroutine immediately continues in the other context and then comes back to the caller's context.

Comment: so if i use withContext the coroutine will continue to next block, but if i use suspendCoroutine it will block until i resume it ?

Comment: There is no explicit suspension/resumption in `withContext`.